# Reduce Window Border Size?

Tags: 11.04, themes, window

One of the [***most* annoying**](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2006/08/fitts-law-and-infinite-width.html) things about Ubuntu is probably the ~3-5-pixel border distance between the buttons on the title bar and the top and right sides of the window.

[image]

Is there any way to reduce that to zero?

Comment: Why is it annoying?

Comment: @user unknown: See [this](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2006/08/fitts-law-and-infinite-width.html) (search for "pixel") and [this](http://www.asktog.com/basics/firstPrinciples.html#fittsLaw).

Comment: @Mehrdad: those articles are an interesting read. I'm guessing you're looking for a theme similar to Clearlooks, with the buttons extended to the top and right edges of their window, in an Ubuntu Classic session with the top panel removed?

Comment: @Warrioring64: You read my mind! Yes.

Answer (score 3):

Okay, I found **part** of the solution:

Go open `/usr/share/themes/Clearlooks/metacity-1/metacity-theme-1.xml` and modify the `right="1" top="2"` values in the line saying

```
<frame_geometry name="normal" ...>
    ...
    <border name="button_border" left="1" right="1" top="2" bottom="1"/>
</frame_geometry>
```

This fixes the button issues.

However, this **does NOT work** for the title bar frame! If I go to the top of a maximized window's title bar and double-click it, it doesn't toggle the maximization. I need to move down the mouse by a few pixels to do that.

If anyone knows how to fix that part as well, that'd be great! Otherwise this is my best answer so far.

Answer (score 0):

There are many window border themes in Ubuntu, some of which nearly don't have a border at all. Try one of these.

Comment: The New Wave theme is the first one that comes to mind for me.

Comment: Yeah but they're ugly. :( (And besides, New Wave still has a border on the right side.) Any way to do this with ClearLooks?

Answer (score 0):

The Adwaita theme for GNOME Shell seemed to me like it would be what you're looking for, and after a quick search on gnome-look.org I found a [GTK 2.x version](http://gnome-look.org/content/show.php/Gnome+3++Unreleased+Edition?content=135862) of it. Note that you will need the Equinox GTK+ theming engine installed for it to look right, but it's easy enough to find in the Ubuntu Software Center.